# Controller Manager not available

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, controller-manager, ros2-controllers, gazebo-ros2-control

I'm facing an issue with controlling a robot in Gazebo using ROS 2 and ros2_control. I'm running ROS 2 with the Humble distribution on Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed the necessary packages including ros2_control, gazebo_ros2_control, and others.

I am trying to test using a default package just to show my errors. The errors I encounter are

```
robotics$ ros2 run controller_manager spawner test_controller
```

> [INFO] [1699614834.933186665] [spawner_test_controller]: Waiting for
> '/controller_manager' node to exist [INFO] [1699614836.952766939]
> [spawner_test_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to
> exist [INFO] [1699614838.971527756] [spawner_test_controller]: Waiting
> for '/controller_manager' node to exist [INFO] [1699614840.991855230]
> [spawner_test_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to
> exist [ERROR] [1699614843.012806033] [spawner_test_controller]:
> Controller manager not available [ros2run]: Process exited with
> failure 1

```
robotics$ ros2 run controller_manager controller_manager
```

> No executable found

```
robotics$ ros2 run controller_manager ros2_control_node
```

> [image]

and here to list the packages i have

```
robotics$ ros2 pkg list | grep ros2_control
gazebo_ros2_control
ros2_control
ros2_control_test_assets
ros2_controllers

robotics$ ros2 pkg list | grep controller_manager

controller_manager
controller_manager_msgs
moveit_simple_controller_manager

robotics$ ros2 pkg executables controller_manager

controller_manager ros2_control_node
controller_manager spawner
controller_manager unspawner
```

I tried solutions suggested in the [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/413240/ros2-controller-manager-migration-from-foxy-to-humble-controller-manager-not-available/), but still no use.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of text. Instead, copy/paste the actual text and format it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome at RSE.

We released several examples on how to launch gazebo with ros2_control. Please have a look on how to setup your urdf files, writing your launch files, etc.

- [Example 9 of ros2_control_demos](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_9/doc/userdoc.html)
- [gazebo_ros2_control_demos](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/gazebo_ros2_control/doc/index.html#gazebo-ros2-control-demos)

Comment: Thank you. I found my problem was because of some mistake in the config yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so something similar was happening to me. I see that you resolved your problem (fantastic) by fixing an error in one of your .yaml files, but I think it is worth putting my solution here just in case it can help anyone.

I found that there were multiple "zombie" nodes running in the background which were not allowing my *controller_manger* to execute. You can check for these by running the command:

*ros2 node list*

If you see any nodes that are duplicates or should not be running, you will have to kill them. For ROS2 the best method I found was to just restart your machine.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers